# Text formatting: Tab stops and center?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I'd like to center a text using the middle tab stop. My scale is in `mm` and I cannot find the "right" position in order to place my text precisely in the middle.

On the picture:

**1st line:** Formatted with the tab stop by trying to find the center.

**2nd line:** Formatted with the "center" align text function (cannot be used for setting center and right text on the same line).

**Is there any way to define the exact middle of the sheet (or the width of the cell when I am inside a table) ?**

edit:

I want to be able to place the tab stop at the middle but I cannot since half of the sheet's width is not a round value.

A4 `210mm x 297mm`

Width of the sheet : `210mm`

Right and left margin: `2 x 25.4mm`

Available width of the sheet: `210 - (2x25.4) = 159.2mm`

Middle: `159.2mm / 2 =` = **79.6mm** => Word round this value to 80mm or 79mm => It is not the middle, I get an offset.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyM6s.jpg]

Comment: repeating your case it works well in my pc (same Word 2013). Are you sure indentation is the same in both paragraph and tab stop is exactly at the middle of it? What is the practical problem where this difference cause you problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can't be reproduced.

Comment: I thought I explained pretty well enough... Indentation is the same everywhere. `tab stop is exactly at the middle of it`... really ?! It is my question ! I want to be able to place the tab stop at the middle but I cannot since half of the sheet's width is not a round value. Is there any `magnet` like powerpoint in order to find the exact middle position ?

Comment: there is no magnet, but you can type it exactly where you want. Just right click on the paragraph then go to paragraph settings - tab stop. "I thought I explained pretty well enough..." - no you didn't, there are still a lot of useful new information in your comment. Please edit the question and include them in it.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: you can just set text indentation to "center", you can do it for each cell. Why do you want to use tabs instead of it? Your question seems to be an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please give more background to your question.

Comment: In order to have a word centered and another left aligned, in the same cell. Exactly the same reason why we use tab stops but inside a table's cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of drag and drop tab stop characters, you can manually enter its location:

- Right click on the paragraph, where you try to add the tab.
- Select "Paragraph..." ; click "Tabs..."
- type the desired location (e.g. 79.6 mm), select `Center` and press `Set` then `Ok`

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is fixed, he didn't want to set this value... I need to calculate the middle everytime ? Means I am in a table and I want to change the width of the cell, I need to calculate the middle again ? Thank you !